# Using break statements in a basic script

Tags: python

Below is a simple calculator program in which I'm using `break` statements to control the logic, I was wondering if this is overkill on the `break` statements or is it OK.

```
while True:
try:
    print("Choose operation(+ | - | * | / | Enter 'e' to exit)")
    op=input()
    if op!="+" and op!="-" and op!="*" and op!="/" and op!="e":
        print("Invalid input, you must choose an option from the menu.")
        break
    elif op=="e":
        break
    else:
        print(">")
        val1=float(input(val1))
        print(">")
        val2=input()
        val2=float(input(val2))
        if op=="+":
            print("= ", val1+val2)
        elif op=="-":
            print("= ", val1-val2) 
        elif op=="*":
            print("= ", val1*val2)
        else:
            print("= ", val1/val2)  
except ValueError:  
    print("Input must be numerical.")  
    break 
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Dividing by zero is undefined.")
    break
exit()
```

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Comment: Why do you read `val2` twice? The first will simply be discarded.

Comment: Why would you exit the program when the user types invalid input? They are _more_ likely to want to try again if they fumble on the keyboard.

Comment: ``break`` exits your loop. So instead of asking us, if ``break`` is okay to use, you should ask yourself: do I want to exit my loop or do I want to keep it running? Removing ``break`` changes how your app behaves.

Comment: I understand, I have another version where I use loops to allow the user to try as many times as they want. I was just wondering about the break statements on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

Basically what I did is to fix the indentations, remove the twice `val2`, remove the `exit()` call, put everything in one function, and call it from another `while True` loop.
If the input will be wrong, the program will call the function again and try to ask the user for good input. and if the user input was `e`, the function returns "EXIT" and then the program will terminate.

By the way, you can do this without functions and with 2 nested for loops, though I don't think it will look good as now.

```
def calculator():
    while True:
        try:
            print("Choose operation(+ | - | * | / | Enter 'e' to exit)")
            op=input()
            if op not in ("+", "-", "*", "/", "e"):    # Changed that too, more simple now
                print("Invalid input, you must choose an option from the menu.")
                break
            elif op == "e":
                return "EXIT"
            else:
                print(">")
                val1=float(input())
                print(">")
                val2=float(input())
                if op == "+":
                    print("= ", val1+val2)
                elif op == "-":
                    print("= ", val1-val2)
                elif op == "*":
                    print("= ", val1*val2)
                else:
                    print("= ", val1/val2)
        except ValueError:
            print("Input must be numerical.")
            break
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print("Dividing by zero is undefined.")
            break
    return "OK"

while True:
    if calculator() == "EXIT":
        break
```

And that is the solution with multiple functions:

```
def is_valid(user_input):
    if user_input not in ("+", "-", "*", "/", "e"):
        print("Invalid input, you must choose an option from the menu.")
        return False
    return True

def result(val1, val2, op):
    if op == "+":
        print("= ", val1 + val2)
    elif op == "-":
        print("= ", val1 - val2)
    elif op == "*":
        print("= ", val1 * val2)
    else:
        if val2 != 0:
            print("= ", val1 / val2)
        else:
            print("Dividing by zero is undefined.")

def caculater():
    while True:
            op=input("Choose operation(+ | - | * | / | Enter 'e' to exit)\n")
            if not is_valid(op):
                break
            if op == "e":
                return "e"
            else:
                try:
                    val1=float(input("> "))
                    val2=float(input("> "))
                    result(val1, val2, op)
                except ValueError:
                    print("Input must be numerical.")
    return "OK"

while True:
    if caculater() == "e":
        break
```

Comment: I did want to exit the entire loop when a mistake is made, thats the intention, yes and the extra read for val2 was a mistake, I meant to take it out. I have heard that the over use of break statements is a bad idea. I was asking if there is something inherently wrong with using them to control the logic of the program or if this is just a matter of preference, I understand what they are for.

Comment: I didnt want to use a function, just wanted it to be a simple as possible. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to see a solution with function? it really makes it even more simple and clear

Comment: No of course, I would love to, let's see it.

Comment: What were the mistakes other than reading in val2 twice?

Comment: The other mistakes: using the `exit()` function at the end of the code, you don't need that, and the indentation wasn't correct. I edited my solution, take a look now and tell me if it's good for you

Comment: Nice, thank you. Yeah I normally don't use the exit function but for some reason the program would not terminate... Prolly just a logical error on my part.

Comment: I was wondering, would it be better to make one function to house pretty much all of the code and then small functions for each task inside of that like one for reading in and validating operation and one for preforming the calculation and so on or would that be over kill?

Comment: Is returning "EXIT" in all caps conventional or would it be ok to return something like "e"?

Comment: It won't be overkill at all. you can split it into few functions and I edited the post and showed you that solution too. And the "EXIT" is my choice, it can be True/false/e/what ever you want. Btw id you liked the solution and it helped you I will appreciate if you accept the answer :)

Comment: Did I accept your answer correctly Eladtopaz? I am a bit new to the stack. And yeah, thats what im calling it, the stack lol.

Comment: You did accept it correctly, thank you Daniel and I am glad I helped you :)